# How do I mass-ban members in the new interface (neo) of Yahoo Groups?

Tags: yahoo, yahoo-groups

Prior to switching UI to the "neo" interface, Yahoo Groups allowed us to enter several email addresses or Yahoo IDs and ban them (URL used to be at: `http://groups.yahoo.com/group/<groupname>/ban_members`). This enabled me to easily maintain and update a banlist for all of my groups.

The new interface doesn't seem to have that feature. Does anybody know?